# Flutter Google Map Crash when navigate one screen to another screen in android phone

Tags: android, ios, flutter

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:139)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@234914064@23.49.14 (200306-0):26)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@234914064@23.49.14 (200306-0):29)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.d.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@234914064@23.49.14 (200306-0):23)

Comment: Could you provide relevant part of code, where it crashed? So we can help you further.

Comment: GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: false,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
            zoomControlsEnabled: false,
            // markers: driverDashboardProvider.markers,
            minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(9.0, null),
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
           
            }),